# Visual Studio 2015 with github plugin issue

Tags: github, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to using github with visual studio 2015 plugin and I'm stuck.

I created a new project on github and was able to link the depot to my visual studio project. I was able to sync some code up to the depot.
Then I added a readme file to my project on github from the website. Next day I made more code and decided to sync it up to the depot, but now it says that I have incoming commits (the readme file). I clicked on fetch on the incoming commit but nothing happens. I clicked on pull and it says my changes would be overwritten by merge.

I then went to outgoing commit (the ones i just made) and click on push. it says that "You cannot push branch master to remote origin because there are new commits in the remote repository’s branch. Pushing this branch would result in a non-fast-forward update on the branch in the remote repository"

i click on several things and i still can't resolve this issue. I want to update my current project with the readme and then update my depot. (i also am new to the terminology)

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that you've got changes on the server, that are committed, and changes to some of the same files on your local copy that conflict with it to the extent that Git can't figure out which ones should "win".

You'll have to look at each file that has conflicts, understand where the conflicts are, sort them out, tell git that you've sorted out the file, and then progress.

So `Fetch` will bring all of the changes down from github, locally, but not change your working copy.

`Merge` is intended to pull down the changes in your current branch and merge them in (and that's where it's having trouble).

Best recommendation for working with git (whether Visual Studio or not)): Fetch and merge **often**.  Every day at least.

This page looks like a reasonable tutorial on how to do it.  It looks similar to my VS2015 git plugins.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286559.aspx

This page is quite a good tutorial on doing it from the command line:

https://easyengine.io/tutorials/git/git-resolve-merge-conflicts/

(But I've got to say: the Visual Studio tool makes it easier).

So the key points are:

- look at each file and fix the conflicts.
- tell git that you've fixed the file
- Once you've done all the files, you need to "commit the merge"

Then you're in a place to commit your local changes and push them up to the server.

Second tip: Most people that I know who use git with visual studio also use the command line client extensively, and usually have an additional gui client (such as Atlassian's Sourcetree) as well.  I use all three every day.

Comment: I tried to use the microsoft solution. I click on Fetch but it never seems to fetch anything, and it does not say there's a conflict that i need to resolve. Then I tried the easyengine.io and performed the grep -lr '<<<<<<<' . command. it gave me nothing. I am using MINGW64 and when i go to the project directory it does say "MASTER" next to the directory name.

Comment: Can you do a `git status` and `git branch -a` and post the output?

Comment: $ git status
On branch master
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   .gitattributes
        new file:   .gitignore

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        FalloutShelterSaveEditor.sln


Hyperian@Hyperian-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/projects/FalloutShelterSaveEditor (master)

Comment: $ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master

Hyperian@Hyperian-PC MINGW64 ~/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/projects/FalloutShelterSaveEditor (master)

Comment: What I would do from here, and what git pros would do from here are two different things.  What **I** would do is clone a new copy of your repo, into a new folder, copy those three local files in and commit them.  (And then when I can see the changed files on github, I'd delete the first folder and work only on the new one). What **might** work is, from the command line, do `git pull` and see what it complains about (because it might be better than Visual Studios), and fix that.

Comment: I did a git pull and it says $ git pull
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        .gitattributes
Please commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
.

Comment: so you're saying i should just restart? I could, but i rather figure out how to do this properly, since even SVN or perforce can handle this simply, i dont know why i would use github at all if it can't even deal with this issue.

Comment: Stash will probably do it.  I do something like `git stash save MyChanges` - which "stashes them away" in some sort of stack - takes them out of the current changes, but puts them somewhere that git can get them back.  So then you should be able to do `git pull` (because you've stashed them as it says).  If that gets the latest from the server, you then go `git stash pop` and it "pops" your last stash from the stash stack.

Comment: I haven't managed to find a way to make Visual Studio git tools do a stash.  Sourcetree will.  (but I use the command line)

Comment: I did what you said and stashed my changes, then git pull, then git pushed, then git stash pop, then git pushed. That seems to fix my problem. Thanks

Comment: Good effort. The more time I spend with git, the more I like my dog. :-)